# Django need show exchange rate via xml file

Tags: python, django

I want to show the US dollar currency on my website.

There is have xml file for currency;
http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml

I have no idea how to get this information in. For example, how I can take USD and EUR data on my website. (I would be very happy if you give the sample code.) Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something Django specific.

You can use python's built in support for XMLs alongside requests library:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree
rsp = requests.get('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml')
something = ElementTree.fromstring(rsp.content)
```

After this you can iterate through it and display it in whatever way you want.